# Error when attempting to Export data to Excel.

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, telerik, export

I have a button that exports data from telerik's RadGrid into an Excel document.

However, I am encountering the following error when I attempt to export:

```
[System.Threading.ThreadAbortException]: 
{Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}
```

Here's my code:

```
private void GenerateFile(object structure, string fileName)
{
    Workbook workbook = structure as Workbook;

    var formatProvider = new XlsxFormatProvider();

    try
    {
        using (MemoryTributary ms = new MemoryTributary())
        {
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

            formatProvider.Export(workbook, ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);

            Response.End();
            }
        }
        catch (System.OutOfMemoryException ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the following solutions based on posts I have found online that dealt with the same issue, none of the solutions have worked:

- Change "Response.End()" to "HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()"
- Change "Response.End()" to "HttpContext.Current.Response.End()"
- Move "Response.End()" inside a *finally* block.
- Move "Response.End()" outside of the try-catch scope.

None of the above solutions have solved the issue. Any further advice on how to resolve this error is greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: First, remove that `catch` block. If you get an exception you should investigate and fix it, not try to cover it up. Second, `Response.End` means end processing immediately, as in abort the thread immediately. You literally asked to abort the thread

Comment: Why do you use `Response.End()`? It's not needed

Answer (score 1):

You are causing the exception by calling [Response.End](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end(v=vs.110).aspx). `End`'s documented behavior is to flush buffers and abort the current request immediately by aborting it. It's not used in .NET programming. It's there only for compatibility with old ASP code.

Just remove `Response.End()` from your code

You should also remove the `catch` statement. Exceptions should be investigated and fixed, not covered up. An OutOfMemoryException means that there is something seriously wrong with the code that's causing leaks. It can be caused either because you run out of memory or because memory is so fragmented that .NET is unable to allocate a large enough block

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the catch statement, always appreciate feedback on my code. After following your suggestion, and removing the Response.End from my code, the file does not download, Excel simply opens up, and I get an error saying there was a problem with some content in my file. And it can try and recover as much as possible.